# Wget which stops when it has a download limit

Tags: linux, debian, shell, script, wget

I have over 200 wget in screens on my server. I set a download limit in each low wget: `--limit-rate=1K`. The only problem is that after one hundred seconds, he considers as a finished one, so this stream file that doesn't have no download limit.

Here the command:

```
screen -dmS t wget The_URL_was_hidden -O /dev/null --limit-rate=1K --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
```

I found that when I increase the limit, the execution time of the download remains infinite. But I don't want to increase this limit. Can you help me? I'm confused. Sorry for my bad English, I'm from France.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this setup?
It's rather inefficient and depending on the goal there are multiple better ways...

Comment: That system is okay for me, just download limit makes complete my own download ... you have idea of the problem? I tried a single download with 1kB / s but it still has stopped downloading ...